# getting {{action}} to work in ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I've got a simple Ember app, but I spent 5 hours to get a {{action}} to work without any luck. I've tried everything I could think of 3 times but I'm stuck.
I've got minimal routers. There is an index.handlebars that is displayed by default in the {{outlet}} and there is a link to a pricing page, that when clicked successfully transitions to the pricing page. In the pricing page I tried a  and a  to include an {{action showMessage}} which has a corresponding method in the PricingController. Looking with the ember-extention in Chrome I can see that the PricingController is indeed associated with the view. But the method is never called.
I really don't know what else to try.

the application.handlebars:

```
<div class='navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top'>
  <div class='navbar-inner'>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='nav-collapse collapse'>
        <ul class='nav'>
          <li>{{#linkTo 'pricing'}}Prijzen{{/linkTo}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='container' id='main'>
  <div class='content'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='span12'>
        <div class='page-header'></div>
        {{outlet}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('pricing');
});


App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
});


App.PricingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
});
```

pricing.handlebars:

```
<h1>some text</h1>
<a href="#" {{action showMessage}} class='btn btn-primary btn-large'>order</a>
<button {{action showMessage}}></button>

App.PricingController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  showMessage: function() {
    toastr.info('info');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working correctly in the latest emberRCjs and handlebarsrc3. Which version of ember and handlebars are you using?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to create the fiddle. Not sure what happened started and stopped the server a couple of times, and also the browser. I'm on "head" with ember-rails. I just did it in another place and it worked straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the JS console for clues, my guess is that this should be throwing a "showMessage was not handled" error.
This is because by default the {{action}} helper targets the current route not the controller

You can either move the `showMessage` function to an events object on the route

```
App.PricingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {
    showMessage: function() {
      toastr.info('info');
    }
  }
});
```

or set the action's target to the controller

```
<a href="#" {{action showMessage target="controller"}}>Show</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Bradley. There were no error messages in the console. I did try to specify the target, I'll give it another go. The [ember docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/) still talk about the controller being the default target.